# Hide columns except first column on expand/collapse table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table with one header and columns, and I am expand/collapse based on header click by the below code:

```
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
```

My table is below:

[image: Table]

What I need is. When I click first then it should collapse and show only first column that mean the column with data1 others should hide as below:

[image: After collapse]

And it should show <kbd>+</kbd> button and when I click again it should go back to previous state.

Please note fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud7yj6w2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

> ```
> $(this).toggleClass('expand').next('tr').find('td').not('td:first')
> ```

To exclude the first `td`.

---

Use this if you have more than one row:

> ```
> $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextAll('tr').find('td').not('td:first-child').slideToggle(100);
> ```

### Demo

```js
$('.header').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextAll('tr').find('td').not('td:first-child').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .sign:after {
  content: "+";
  display: inline-block;
}

.header.expand .sign:after {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr class="header expand">
    <th colspan="4">Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
    <td>data3</td>
    <td>data4</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
    <td>data3</td>
    <td>data4</td>
  </tr>


</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user1365067 No problem I added an alternate line if you have more than one row.

Comment: I had an answer. Deleted it. Yours were better ;)